# MySQL table of languages spoken with their full printable name and ISO code

Tags: mysql, iso

For example, `Spanish` is `ES` while `German` is `DE` and so on.

Does anyone know where I could find a MySQL table-dump of all of the languages available with their name and iso codes?

Here's a list to show you what I'm talking about: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_language_codes.asp

Comment: with the information from w3schools, I dun see how hard to convert it as a table.

Comment: I do not know what you are talking about, ajreal. I was thinking maybe someone already had a MySQL table at hand and they could pass it here. I don't know...

Comment: you are odd ... does not that page have the data you are looking for?

Comment: Yes but I do not see how I can convert as table... you mean by hand? Oh that is so long and painful T_T

Comment: you can view source, save the HTML, parse the text file. Or simply copy and paste into a text editor (surely is already 80~90% of CSV formatted) ... moody

Comment: You're looking for [ISO 639](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639), perhaps that will help your googling. BTW, stay away from http://w3fools.com/ please, they're not a very good reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't take you more than 2 minutes. I just did it!

1. Open w3 schools page on firefox
2. Select table contents. Then Edit -> Copy
3. Paste on a text editor. I did on Gedit (Ubuntu) . In this step you already have a text file with tabs as separators (so, it is already a .csv file with tabs instead of commas). You can replace tabs (\t) with commas, if you feel more comfortable.
4. Save the text file. You can name it 'iso639.csv'
5. Import the contents on your mysql table.
6. Have a break after the hard work! ;-)

Comment: Here is what I have so far: http://pastebin.com/izMqKJEx

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean [ISO-639](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639) language codes. There's a pretty concise list on the website of [the Library of Congress](http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php), it even contains the three-letter codes for languages like `ast` for `Asturian` and `hsb` for `High Sorbian`. Not in MySQL dump format but that conversion should be pretty easy.

EDIT: Or just copypaste the table from w3schools.

Comment: I do not know how to "convert" :(